# How to validate single checkbox in php script

Tags: php

In the below code i have one check box i don't no how to validate checkbox.

I have a checkbox if it is uncheck it should give message please accept the agreement.

please help me friends

```
<?php 

$firstname = $lname = "";
$firstnameErr = $lnameErr = "";

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']== "POST") {
   $valid = true;

    /*FirstName Validation starts here*/     
    if(empty($_POST["fname"])) {
        $firstnameErr = "*firstname is Required";
        $valid=false;
    } else {
        $firstname = test_input($_POST["fname"]);   
    } 

    /*LastName Validation starts here*/  
    if(empty($_POST["lname"])) {
        $lnameErr = "*lastname is Required";
        $valid=false;
    } else {
        $lname=test_input($_POST["lname"]); 
    }

    if (isset($_POST['confirm'])) {
        // do something
    }

    //if valid then redirect
    if($valid){
      echo 'success';    
        exit;
    }  
}

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

?>



<form method="post" action="example.php">
    firstname<input type="text" name="fname"/><?php echo $firstnameErr?><br /><br />
    lastname<input type="text" name="lname"/><?php echo $lnameErr?><br /><br />

    <input type="checkbox" name="agree" />
    Agree the terms and condition

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form>
```

please help me friends

Comment: $agree = $_POST['agree'];

Comment: Specify value for your checkbox. Then run a if statement -- if ($_POST['agree'] == your value){run comply code}else{error message}

Comment: @Dorvalla nope: accessing $_POST['agree'] directly before checking if it is set, will throw an error when someone hasn't clicked the radio button

Comment: @ReinderWit Ahh, my bad, forgot that part upon entering page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**please go through the below code.I think it will work fine.**

```
  <?php 
    $firstname=$lname="";
    $firstnameErr=$lnameErr="";

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']== "POST") {
       $valid = true;

    /*FirstName Validation starts here*/     
     if(empty($_POST["fname"]))
    {
        $firstnameErr="*firstname is Required";
            $valid=false;
    }
    else
    {
    $firstname=test_input($_POST["fname"]); 
    } 
     /*LastName Validation starts here*/     
    if(empty($_POST["lname"]))
    {
        $lnameErr="*lastname is Required";
            $valid=false;
    }
    else
    {
    $lname=test_input($_POST["lname"]); 
    }

    if(empty($_POST["agree"]))
    {
        $agreeErr="*check box is Required";
            $valid=false;
    }
    else
    {
    $agree=test_input($_POST["agree"]); 
    }

    if (isset($_POST['confirm'])) {
        // do something
    }

     //if valid then redirect
      if($valid){

          echo 'success';    
        exit;
      }  
    }

    function test_input($data)
    {
         $data = trim($data);
         $data = stripslashes($data);
         $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
         return $data;
    }

    ?>



    <form method="post" action="example.php">
    firstname<input type="text" name="fname"/><?php echo $firstnameErr?><br /><br />
    lastname<input type="text" name="lname"/><?php echo $lnameErr?><br /><br />

    <input type="checkbox" name="agree" /><?php echo $agreeErr?>
    Agree the terms and condition

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you checkbox is checked, it will be passed to your PHP, otherwise it won't, so just use the `isset()` function:

```
if (!isset($_POST['agree'])) {
    echo "Please accept the agreement";
}
```